# Chrome Autofill enabled, but does not fill in

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, autofill

I have a form that works with Safari, but not with Chrome Autofill.

[Screen shot autofill suggestion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vS7dX.png)

[Screen shot after selected "Adriaan"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crsKd.png)

Code to generate input fields:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(vars, function(variable) {
        modal = modal + " \
        <div class='form-group row' style='padding-left: 5%; padding-right: 5%;'> \
            <div class='input-group'> \
                 <span class='input-group-addon' id='"+variable+"icon'><i class='fa "+icons[variable]+"' aria-hidden='true'>&nbsp;</i><label for='"+variable+"'>"+labels[variable]+"</label></span> \
                 <input type='"+types[variable]+"' name='"+names[variable]+"' id="+variable+" placeholder='"+placeholders[variable]+"' required autocomplete='"+autocomp[variable]+"' autocomplete='on' class='form-control' style='position: relative;'></input> \
            </div> \
        </div>";
});
```

HTML code generated on webpage:

```
<div class="form-group row" style="padding-left: 5%; padding-right: 5%;">                                               
   <div class="input-group">                                                        
       <span class="input-group-addon" id="firstnameicon"><i class="fa " aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</i><label for="firstname">First Name</label></span>                                                  
       <input type="text" name="fname" id="firstname" placeholder="John" required="" autocomplete="given-name" class="form-control" style="position: relative;">                                                
   </div>
</div>
```

Anyone some ideas to make this autofill work correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a suggestion, have you tried generating `autocomplete="on"` instead of `autocomplete="given-name"`?

Source taken from `[w3school][1]`

Comment: Ok, yes, I thought I tried before, but I wrote autocomplete="given-name" autocomplete="on" and then "on" was overwritten... So this works! Thanks!